# Dataframes not joining using dplyr while using two criteria

Tags: r, join, time, dplyr, tidyverse

So I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("05/14/2019", "05/14/2019", "05/16/2019", 
"05/17/2019", "05/18/2019", "05/18/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/25/2019", 
"05/26/2019"), TIME = c("10:30 AM", "11:15 AM", "11:00 PM", " 7:36 AM", 
"11:15 AM", " 7:00 PM", " 2:45 PM", " 3:02 AM", "12:40 PM")), row.names = 355:363, class = "data.frame")
```

Subset of course, but I would like to join in info from another df, from here:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Date = c("05/14/2019", "05/14/2019", "05/16/2019", 
"05/17/2019", "05/18/2019", "05/18/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/25/2019", 
"05/26/2019", "05/31/2019"), TIME = c("10:30 AM", "11:15 AM", 
"11:00 PM", "7:36 AM", "11:15 AM", "7:00 PM", "2:45 PM", "3:02 AM", 
"12:40 PM", "2:10 PM"), Event_ = c("71", "68", "03", "38", "58", 
"70", "70", "17", "54", "38")), row.names = 343:352, class = "data.frame")
```

I get the following on the join, which returns NA's on matches that should be there. No idea why it isn't working.

```
df1 %>%  
   left_join(df2, by = c('Date', 'TIME') )


structure(list(Date = c("05/14/2019", "05/14/2019", "05/16/2019", 
"05/17/2019", "05/18/2019", "05/18/2019", "05/20/2019", "05/25/2019", 
"05/26/2019"), TIME = c("10:30 AM", "11:15 AM", "11:00 PM", " 7:36 AM", 
"11:15 AM", " 7:00 PM", " 2:45 PM", " 3:02 AM", "12:40 PM"), 
    Event_ = c("71", "68", "03", NA, "58", NA, NA, NA, "54")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

What about these are causing the join to only work sometimes??? The join only works 1/4 of the time in the larger dataframe and I am bewildered as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: your columns are not actually datetime objects and just character strings representing the date and time, thus spaces, punctuation and capitalization are critical for a proper match.

You have some leading whitespace on some of the times in df1.
Trim the whitespace and it should work as expected.

```
df1$TIME<-trimws(df1$TIME)
df1 %>%  
  left_join(df2, by = c('Date', 'TIME') )

        Date     TIME Event_
1 05/14/2019 10:30 AM     71
2 05/14/2019 11:15 AM     68
3 05/16/2019 11:00 PM     03
4 05/17/2019  7:36 AM     38
5 05/18/2019 11:15 AM     58
6 05/18/2019  7:00 PM     70
7 05/20/2019  2:45 PM     70
8 05/25/2019  3:02 AM     17
9 05/26/2019 12:40 PM     54
```

Answer (score 1):

As Dave2e notes, R is currently treating your dates and times as ordinary character strings. Trimming the whitespace works perfectly well in this case. If you wanted to format them as date-time (POSIXlt) objects you could do something like this:

```
# format date-time
df1$datetime <- strptime(paste(df1[,1], df1[,2]), '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
df2$datetime <- strptime(paste(df2[,1], df2[,2]), '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')

# (Optional) remove old date time columns
df1 <- df1[-c(1:2)]
df2 <- df2[-c(1:2)]

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = 'datetime')

             datetime Event_
1 2019-05-14 10:30:00     71
2 2019-05-14 11:15:00     68
3 2019-05-16 23:00:00     03
4 2019-05-17 07:36:00     38
5 2019-05-18 11:15:00     58
6 2019-05-18 19:00:00     70
7 2019-05-20 14:45:00     70
8 2019-05-25 03:02:00     17
9 2019-05-26 12:40:00     54
```

This isn't necessary for merging in this case but could be useful for other tasks like plotting a time series.